# How to break a loop using MouseListener java

Tags: java, mouselistener

I am trying to make an A* pathfinding algorithm my code goes something like this

```
public class Board extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
     if (StartAndEnd())
         AStar();
   }
}
```

Now the problem is that the AStar pathfinding algorithm takes alot of time to compute and I want to break it incase the user makes another choice. (another start and end input with the mouse).

How can I do that?

Comment: Use a Thread/Runnable that can be stopped

Comment: Refer to [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: So why didn't you use threads?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: How to interrupt a program partway through execution with a mouseclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042720/java-how-to-interrupt-a-program-partway-through-execution-with-a-mouseclick)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small demo program that creates a JFrame (window) with a Stop button. It loops for 10,000 seconds unless you press the stop button.

The stop button sets a flag which terminates the loop.

Hopefully you can figure out how to solve your original problem from this code. I've modified the example to call runLongTime in a new thread, leaving the Swing GUI thread alone.

```
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Stoppable extends Thread implements ActionListener
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        final Stoppable app = new Stoppable ();
        app.start ();
    }

    private final JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Stoppable");

    private final JButton stop = new JButton ("Stop");

    private final JPanel panel = new JPanel ();

    private boolean isRunning = true;

    public Stoppable ()
    {
        panel.add (stop);
        frame.setContentPane (panel);
        stop.addActionListener (this);
        frame.pack ();
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }

    @Override
    public void run ()
    {
        try
        {
            runLongTime ();
        }
        catch (final InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        System.exit (0);
    }

    private void runLongTime () throws InterruptedException
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000 && isRunning; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf ("Iteration %d\n", i);
            Thread.sleep (1000);
        }
        System.out.printf ("Stopped\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will block the GUI actions while running, though

Comment: Right, I've modified the example to use a separate thread.

Comment: Except you should really prefer using a SwingWorker https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html

Comment: If you like. I was sticking to basic concepts.